Confused about defer error handling and defer recover in go
I am confused about defer keyword while learning golang

defer in error handling

package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func handleErr(err error) {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

func returnErr() (err error) {
    defer handleErr(err)

    return errors.New("boo")
}

func main() {
    returnErr()
}

why is the output nil?

defer recover

package main

func raisePanic() {
    defer recover()

    panic("boo")
}

func main() {
    raisePanic()
}


why it still panic?
Thanks a lot.

For the second part, this question has the answer.

Both of your questions are caused by the same reason, let’s explain it from source code perspective. The key part of code is located in normalizeGoDeferCall. As the comment described

normalizeGoDeferCall normalizes call into a normal function call
with no arguments and no results, suitable for use in an OGO/ODEFER
statement.
When the compiler parse go/defer keyword, the call expression with arguments after them will be parsed as a function with no arguments, hence

defer f(x, y)

will be converted to
x1, y1 := x, y
defer func() { f(x1, y1) }()

Back to your questions

defer error handling

defer handleErr(err)

will be converted to
err1 := err
defer func() { handleErr(err1) }()

err is evaluated and saved anew and passed to handleErr, so it always be nil
The right way to do it is:
defer func() {handleErr(err)}()


defer recover
recover seems to have no arguments, but it is linked to the real implementation gorecover so that it will be converted to

argp := getcallersp()
defer func(){
    gorecover(argp)
}()

    if p != nil && !p.goexit && !p.recovered && argp == uintptr(p.argp) {
        p.recovered = true
        return p.arg
    }

It can be recovered if two argp are equal, but obviously they are not
If we change it like this:
func raisePanic() {
    defer func() {
        recover()
    }()

    panic("boo")
}

The argp is a function registered by calling defer after panic occurs in this case. This function is called by gopanic. Therefore, argp is the sp of gopanic function. It is calculated and passed to gorecover. After comparison, gorecover considers argp is equal to p.argp, so it can be recovered
